# Why the time complexity for shell sort is nlogn in my data?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, shellsort

environment: python3.6, Anaconda 5.1, Jupyter notebook, numba.

I used a random array generated by Python to measure the time complexity of shell sort, but found that its time complexity is more in line with NlogN. 
I understand that the time complexity of shell sort is O(n^2), I am confused.

Shell sort code:

```
def shell_sort(list):
    n = len(list)
    gap = n // 2
    while gap > 0:
        for i in range(gap, n):
            temp = list[i]
            j = i
            while j >= gap and list[j - gap] > temp:
                list[j] = list[j - gap]
                j -= gap
            list[j] = temp
        gap = gap // 2
    return list
```

[shell sort time complexity analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puf7l.png)

Comment: Might want to send code?

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) is only the worst case time complexity, so the algorithm can run in less time than that on a random input and even on average (or even on almost all its inputs...).

Also the complexity of Shellsort depends on the ["gap sequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences) you selected.

Certain gap sequences result in a worst time case smaller than O(n^2), like O(n^1.5) for the gap sequence `1, 4, 13, 40, 121, ...` or even O(nlog^2(n)) for `1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, ...` (both due to Pratt, 1971). In other words: just trying on one input is not significant at all and the claim about O(n^2) may be false depending on the exact implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: But my gap is set 2, the simplest one. The code is got from wikipeidia, the most basic shell sort, that's why I am so confused.

Comment: @Xander nlogn belongs to O(n^2) so there is no issue if for some, even many, cases the time is closer to nlog than to n^2. If you have other questions you should post the code used to generate the random arrays and compute the average times. If there is an issue with your code it might be because you are not generating actually random arrays  but arrays with a certain bias.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a lot of problems relative to Shell sort complexity and it is suspected that with some appropriate choice of parameters and for some inputs, its complexity could be O(n.logn).

Comment: I used 20 random array samples to test the average time for each size (10-1000000 input capacity), so why is it O(nlogn) instead of O(n^2)?

Comment: So you think 20 «random» array other a set of billions or more is representative? Even if it is the case, n^2 is for the worst case then random choice of set to sort is probably a bad way to generate a worst case. Giacomo answered about gap choices that may change the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I have studied shellsort for smaller n and I can state unequivocally that the gap sequence that produces the best average (number of comparisons) for n = 10, which my software tested on n! different orderings (the entire set) and on 2^(n-2) gap sequences (all possible sequences for n = 10) is {9,6,1}.

The average is clearly O(n * log(n)) as is the worst case.

The best case is similar to insertion sort's n-1 comparisons - O(n) complexity - best case (already ordered data) not only because it can be similarly calculated:

(n-9)+(n-6)+(n-1) = (n * # of gaps)-sum(gaps) = 14.

I know that most would say this is O(n * log(n)) complexity. Personally, I think this is unwarranted because it does not need to be estimated: for any n worked on by any gap sequence the best case is easily and exactly determined.

I'll be stubborn and drive this home: let's just assume, for the sake of argument, that the best case for any shellsort is (n * # of gaps). For n = 10 & # of gaps = 3 the best case would be 10 * 3 or 30. Would this be O(n) complexity? I can see why it could be. Yet shellsort's best case is significantly less than (n * # of gaps) so why is it O(n * log(n))?

It is possible (though extreeeeemely unlikely) that the OP managed to pinpoint the best (or close to it) gap sequence for his n, resulting in O(n * log(n)) complexity. But determining that requires more analysis than guts can provide.